# How can i wait for async result in other method

Tags: angular

I am having waiting for async call problems.

I am working on new project and there i don't want to change the structure because there are a lot of
reusable methods inside.

I faced one problem where the structure is the following:

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="clickHandler()">Go to today</button>
```

**COMPONENTS TS FILE**

```
users;
  makeApiCallToGetAllUsers() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data', data);
      this.users = data;
    })
  }

  predifinedFilter() {
    // there are some if conditions in which makeApiCallToGetAllUsers is called
    // that is the reason that i use this method, but here i make call directly
    this.makeApiCallToGetAllUsers();
  }

  clickHandler() {
    this.predifinedFilter();
    // wait for makeApiCallToGetAllUsers and then call findSpecificUser
    // where i need all 
    this.findSpecificUser();
  }

  findSpecificUser() {
    console.log('users', this.users);
  }
```

My problem is that i need to wait for `makeApiCallToGetAllUsers` call before i continue on other methods in my logic.

In this case users is undefined because it does not wait for the async call

**what i tried**

```
users;
  async makeApiCallToGetAllUsers() {
    await this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data', data);
      this.users = data;
    })
  }

  async predifinedFilter() {
    await this.makeApiCallToGetAllUsers();
  }

  clickHandler() {
    this.predifinedFilter();
    this.findSpecificUser();
  }

  findSpecificUser() {
    console.log('users', this.users);
  }
```

but it is the same

** i tried also**

```
 users;
   makeApiCallToGetAllUsers(cb) {
     this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data', data);
      this.users = data;
      cb();
    })
  }

   predifinedFilter(cb) {
     this.makeApiCallToGetAllUsers(cb);
  }

  clickHandler() {
    this.predifinedFilter(this.findSpecificUser);
  }

  findSpecificUser() {
    console.log('users', this.users);
  }
```

with callbacks but i get

````
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined```
````

Answer (score 0):

After some time of trying i answered my question.

```
 users;
   makeApiCallToGetAllUsers(cb) {
     this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data', data);
      this.users = data;
      console.log('cb', cb);
      cb(data);
    })
  }

   predifinedFilter(cb) {
     this.makeApiCallToGetAllUsers(cb);
  }

  clickHandler() {
    console.log(this);
    this.predifinedFilter(this.findSpecificUser.bind(this));
  }

  findSpecificUser(data) {
    console.log(this);
    // console.log(that);
    // console.log(that.users);
    this.testing();
  }

  testing() {
    console.log(this.users);
  }
```

we need to bind the method to point to `this`...

Comment: Why don't you return the Observable in `makeApiCallToGetUsers` so that you can subscribe in the outer function ?

Comment: Because it needs to be like this.I know that i can do that.That thing was not discussion of this question